# MySQL 5.6.26 high concurrency dead lock

Tags: mysql, innodb, database-deadlocks

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE `extend_0` ( 
`id` bigint(20) NOT NULL, 
`code` varchar(30) NOT NULL, 
`data_key` varchar(50) NOT NULL, 
`data_value` varchar(200) NOT NULL, 
`create_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
`update_time` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 
`yn` tinyint(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1', 
PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`create_time`), 
UNIQUE KEY `idx_unq_code_data_key` (`code`,`data_key`,`create_time`) USING BTREE, 
KEY `idx_code` (`code`) USING BTREE 
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

When two transactions at the same time delete and insert the same data, sometimes a deadlock happened. The tx_isolation is RR.

For example:

```
DELETE FROM extend_0 WHERE code = '00226915986' AND yn = 1; 

INSERT INTO extend_0 (id, code, data_key, data_value, create_time) VALUES (1133296779049299970, '00226915986', 'consignWare', 'food', '2019-05-28 16:59:42.418'), (1133296779049299971, '00226915986', 'productType', '0001,0006', '2019-05-28 16:59:42.418');
```

Deadlock log:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------ 
2019-05-30 14:48:07 0x7fbb7872c700 
*** (1) TRANSACTION: 
TRANSACTION 125554670, ACTIVE 0 sec starting index read 
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1 
LOCK WAIT 2 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 1 row lock(s) 
MySQL thread id 5148727, OS thread handle 140443189679872, query id 6111057236 192.168.162.16 waybill updating 
DELETE FROM extend_0 WHERE code = '00226915986' AND yn = 1 
*** (1) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED: 
RECORD LOCKS space id 77 page no 3145 n bits 360 index idx_unq_code_data_key of table `waybill_0`.`extend_0` trx id 125554670 lock_mode X waiting 
Record lock, heap no 285 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 4; compact format; info bits 32 
0: len 15; hex 4a4456433030323236393135393836; asc 00226915986;; 
1: len 11; hex 636f6e7369676e57617265; asc consignWare;; 
2: len 4; hex 5cecf87e; asc \ ~;; 
3: len 8; hex 911d8ce2e1ddf000; asc ;; 

*** (2) TRANSACTION: 
TRANSACTION 125554668, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting 
mysql tables in use 1, locked 1 
5 lock struct(s), heap size 1136, 6 row lock(s), undo log entries 3 
MySQL thread id 5148728, OS thread handle 140443156399872, query id 6111057237 192.168.162.16 waybill update 
INSERT INTO extend_0 (id, code, data_key, data_value, create_time) VALUES (i-1, '00226915986', 'consignWare', 'food', '2019-05-28 16:59:42.418'), (i, '00226915986', 'productType', '0001,0006', '2019-05-28 16:59:42.418') 
*** (2) HOLDS THE LOCK(S): 
RECORD LOCKS space id 77 page no 3145 n bits 360 index idx_unq_code_data_key of table `waybill_0`.`extend_0` trx id 125554668 lock_mode X 
Record lock, heap no 285 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 4; compact format; info bits 32 
0: len 15; hex 4a4456433030323236393135393836; asc 00226915986;; 
1: len 11; hex 636f6e7369676e57617265; asc consignWare;; 
2: len 4; hex 5cecf87e; asc \ ~;; 
3: len 8; hex 911d8ce2e1ddf000; asc ;; 

Record lock, heap no 287 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 4; compact format; info bits 32 
0: len 15; hex 4a4456433030323236393135393836; asc 00226915986;; 
1: len 11; hex 70726f6475637454797065; asc productType;; 
2: len 4; hex 5cecf87e; asc \ ~;; 
3: len 8; hex 911d8ce2e1ddf020; asc ;; 

*** (2) WAITING FOR THIS LOCK TO BE GRANTED: 
RECORD LOCKS space id 77 page no 3145 n bits 360 index idx_unq_waybill_code_data_key of table `waybill_0`.`extend_0` trx id 125554668 lock_mode X locks gap before rec insert intention waiting 
Record lock, heap no 285 PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 4; compact format; info bits 32 
0: len 15; hex 4a4456433030323236393135393836; asc JDVC00226915986;; 
1: len 11; hex 636f6e7369676e57617265; asc consignWare;; 
2: len 4; hex 5cecf87e; asc \ ~;; 
3: len 8; hex 911d8ce2e1ddf000; asc ;; 

*** WE ROLL BACK TRANSACTION (1) 
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The transaction2 has lock_mode X already. Why does "lock_mode X locks gap before rec insert intention waiting" happen?

But when we execute the transactions one by one a deadlock does not happen. For example:

```
step1: tx1 begin; delete.....;
step2: tx2 begin; delete.....;
step3: tx1 insert....;
step4: tx2 insert....;
step5: tx1 commit;
```

The deadlock happens only when there is high concurrency; the deadlock looks to be caused by the concurrency of tx1's delete and tx2's insert.

What lock does transaction 1 hold?Why transaction 2 is waiting for transaction 1?

Answer (score 1):

Plan A:

Live with it.  That is, check for errors, see that there is a deadlock, and restart the transaction.  You should have this code even if you go with Plan B.

Plan B:

```
BEGIN;
SELECT ... WHERE code = '00226915986' AND yn = 1  FOR UPDATE;
DELETE ...
INSERT ...
COMMIT;
```

This should force any other connection to *wait* instead of *deadlock*.